# Get global variable address by its name if compiled with debug information

Tags: c++, c, gdb

If I compile some C/C++ program using gcc with -g and/or -ggdb turned on, then if I start the program using gdb, I can print variable value inside gdb.

My question is, without gdb, can I achieve the same thing from inside the program?  At runtime, given the name of the variable (represented as a runtime string), is it possible to read the debug information and then get the address of the variable as well as the type information?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't state clearly, I mean given the name of the variable (a string or const char*) at runtime.

Comment: What platform are you using? If some UNIX variant, read the man page for `dlsym`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, good pointer to `dlsym`.  How about type information?

Comment: C doesn't have that kind of introspection.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I mean how does gdb know the type of some variable then?  I assume it is done by reading the debugging information in the binary, am I correct?  If that's correct, then theoretically it should be possible, right?

Comment: This is essentially writing your own debugger.

Comment: Libgdb might be of interest to you.

Comment: What you might be able to do is have your program attach a gdb process to itself then send commands down a pipe to find information. I have seen this done to generate stack traces (when there were not better options).

Comment: @Keith, IMHO stacktrace can be easily got through some C functions, e.g. libglog can print stacktrace when segment fault or any time you do LOG(FATAL).  I don't think "there is no better options".

Comment: @icando - "When" meant historically, on certain platforms many years ago. Agree it's unlikely to be of use now. But my point is that the technique might be used to approach the OP's problem.

Comment: @Keith, thanks for clarification.  I agree your suggestion might be working, but I guess it would be very slow if the program is attached by gdb.  What I want is some way to read the information from debug information, just as what gdb does, without suffering the huge overhead of gdb.

Comment: @jxh, if I understand correctly, libgdb is not useful for my need here because it just turns gdb into a server.  It just makes starting and controlling gdb easier.  What I am looking for is to figure out a way to avoid the overhead of being attached by gdb.  It should just as light weighted as reading some debug information from binary itself.

Comment: I found [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Applications_Debugging_Techniques/The_interposition_library). You will need to get familiar with `libbfd`.

Answer (score 0):

How about about map file ? It will have info of all globals and its address. All you have to do is parse the map file and get address of the variable (python can help here).

In your program write a small routine to accept address and return value. If you are using it for logging like purpose you can do it over sockets event with a new thread so you don't interfear much with actual progarm.

I have not done this but with objdump / dltool it should be able to get the variable type information, also I am not sure how you can avoid illegal address access (ones that will cause SEG and BUS errors).

On the secod thought what is stopping you from using GDB itself ? You could use stripped version of the image to run and debug sym enabled inage to get variable type and address infomation.

Comment: I want to be able to access variables by their name at RUNTIME from inside of the program without much overhead.  Using gdb requires the process being started or attached by gdb, making everything super slow.  Also it is possible the machine that runs the program is different to the one that builds it, so it doesn't necessary have gdb installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Without any third-party programs or big libraries, you can add simple reflection with a few macros, depending on how ugly you'd like to have it

Here's a working sample:

```
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define DEBUG_VAR_NAMES //undef to remove the tracking

struct GlobalRecord{ //will hold info about variables
    const char* name;
    const char* type;
    const void* addr;
};

#ifdef DEBUG_VAR_NAMES


static const GlobalRecord* global_decl( const char* name, bool set, const GlobalRecord* record ){
    static std::map<const char*, const GlobalRecord*> globals; //holds pointers to all record structs

    if( set )
        globals[name] = record;

    const auto it = globals.find( name );

    if( it == globals.end() )
        return nullptr;     //just return nullptr if a var could not be found
    else
        return it->second;
}


static GlobalRecord global_init( const char* type, const char* name, void* addr, const GlobalRecord* record ) {
    global_decl( name, true, record );
    return GlobalRecord{ name, type, addr };
}

#define COMMA ,
#define DECLARE_GLOBAL_INIT(type, name, init) type name = init; GlobalRecord name##_rec = global_init( #type, #name, (void*)&name, & name##_rec)
#define DECLARE_GLOBAL(type, name) type name; GlobalRecord name##_rec = global_init( #type, #name, (void*)&name, & name##_rec)
#define GET_GLOBAL(name) global_decl(name, false, nullptr)

#else

#define COMMA ,
#define DECLARE_GLOBAL_INIT(type, name, init) type name = init;
#define DECLARE_GLOBAL(type, name) type name;
#define GET_GLOBAL(name) ((const GlobalRecord*) nullptr) //This is a bad idea(TM).

#endif


//SAMPLE HERE
//Declare 3 global vars for testing.

//declaring a variable is pretty simple.
//it's a macro call with <type>, <name>, <optional init value> as arguments:
DECLARE_GLOBAL_INIT( int, my_int, 5 ); //instead of: int my_int = 5;
DECLARE_GLOBAL_INIT( std::string, my_string, "hi there" ); //instead of std::string my_string = "hi there";
DECLARE_GLOBAL( std::map<int COMMA int>, my_map ); //<- commas must be replaced with a macro


void print_var( const char* name ){
    std::cout << '\n';

    if( GET_GLOBAL( name ) == nullptr ){
          std::cout << "Var " << name << " not found.\n";  
          return;
    }

    std::cout << "Variable: " << GET_GLOBAL( name )->name << "\n";
    std::cout << "The address of " << name << " is recorded as: " << GET_GLOBAL( name )->addr << "\n";
    std::cout << "The type of " << name << " is recorded as : " << GET_GLOBAL( name )->type << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    print_var( "my_int" );
    print_var( "my_string" );
    print_var( "my_map" );
    print_var( "my_double" );

    return 0;
}
```

Basically all global variables need to be declared as a macro such as `DECLARE_GLOBAL(type, name)`. Some basic info about the variable will then automatically be stored inside a `std::map` in `global_decl` and can be retrieved from there.

It involves a bunch of petty hackery and should probably not be used just like that. It's more of a pointer to give you an idea of how it could be done.

The good part about that method is that the overhead is practically zero. There is no boilerplate code that would have to be called for your program to read/write variables. The bad part is macros.

If you are looking for a solution *without* changing your code at all, you're probably better off using gdb or a similar tool.

Comment: Well I know this approach.  What I am asking in this question is exactly how to avoid such manual work, but rather automatically, without the need to modify the code.  But anyway thanks for spending time on writing the long answer.